# How can I view the Jump Lists when using multitouch?

Tags: windows-8

The Jump Lists on Taskbar items used to be opened by dragging up from a taskbar icon when using touch, pen or mouse in Windows 7. In windows 8 I can only seem to open them from pen or mouse input, though after a couple dozen attempts with touch I managed to open it a couple times on accident.

Is there a trick to opening the jump list in desktop mode when using multitouch or do I have to "right click" to get it? The press and hold right click for multitouch is much slower than swiping up. If it matters I have an older touchscreen monitor (the kind the Upgrade Assistant complains about) but this function worked fine in Windows 7 on the same pc.

Comment: The upswoop seems to work fine for me with a mouse, so I'm guessing the gesture itself hasn't changed significantly. Perhaps your touch screen needs calibration? Or maybe newer drivers?

Comment: @nhinkle touch itself works fine though, including scrolling. It's the same gesture for pen/mouse and both work

Answer (score 2):

This may be an intentional change to avoid confusing people as they're touch panning. A workaround is to put your finger down on the icon for a few tenths of a second and then swiping up. It's similar to waiting for the right-click trigger, but it seems a little faster to me.